# How to simplify double summation in a sophisticated way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How can I simplify the double summation
$$\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}\left( e ^{-\beta(t_{i+1}-t_j)}-e ^{-\beta(t_i-t_j)}\right)$$
to have only one summation in a sophisticated way? I know a lot of terms cancel out since for $i=1$, the inner summation is
$$e ^{-\beta(t_{2}-t_1)}-e ^{-\beta(t_1-t_1)} = e ^{-\beta(t_{2}-t_1)}-1$$
and for $i=2$,
$$\left( e ^{-\beta(t_{3}-t_1)}-e ^{-\beta(t_2-t_1)}\right)+\left( e ^{-\beta(t_{3}-t_2)}-e ^{-\beta(t_2-t_2)}\right)=\left( e ^{-\beta(t_{3}-t_1)}-e ^{-\beta(t_2-t_1)}\right)+\left( e ^{-\beta(t_{3}-t_2)}-1\right)$$
and so on. In the end, I'm left with
$$\sum^{k}_{i=1}\left( e ^{-\beta(t_k-t_i)}-1\right).$$
However, is there a better way to show this that looks nicer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}\left( e ^{-\beta(t_{i+1}-t_j)}-e ^{-\beta(t_i-t_j)}\right)&=\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1} e ^{-\beta(t_{i+1}-t_j)}-\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1}e ^{-\beta(t_i-t_j)}\\
&=\sum^{k}_{i=2}\sum^{i-1}_{j=1} e ^{-\beta(t_{i}-t_j)}-\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}\sum^i_{j=1} e ^{-\beta(t_i-t_j)}\\
&=\sum^{k}_{i=2}\sum^{i-1}_{j=1} e ^{-\beta(t_{i}-t_j)}-\sum^{k-1}_{i=1}\sum^{i-1}_{j=1} e ^{-\beta(t_i-t_j)}-\sum^{k-1}_{i=1} e ^{-\beta(t_i-t_i)}\\
&=\sum^{k-1}_{j=1} e ^{-\beta(t_{k}-t_j)}-k+1
\end{align*}

Alternately, we sum over the triangle $\{(i,j)|1\le j< i\le k\}$ and subtract the sum over the triangle $\{(i,j)|1\le j\le i<k\}$. So, what is left is the sum over an edge $\{(j,k)|1\le j <k\}$ minus the sum over the diagonal $\{(i,i)|1\le i<k\}$.

Answer (score 1):

After switching the order of the summations, you'll end up with a telescopic sum : \begin{aligned}\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}{\sum_{j=1}^{i}{\left(\operatorname{e}^{-\beta\left(t_{i+1}-t_{j}\right)}-\operatorname{e}^{-\beta\left(t_{i}-t_{j}\right)}\right)}}&=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}{\sum_{i=j}^{k-1}{\left(\operatorname{e}^{-\beta\left(t_{i+1}-t_{j}\right)}-\operatorname{e}^{-\beta\left(t_{i}-t_{j}\right)}\right)}}\\ &=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}{\sum_{i=j}^{k-1}{\left(u_{j}\left(i+1\right)-u_{j}\left(i\right)\right)}}\\ &=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}{\left(u_{j}\left(k\right)-u_{j}\left(j\right)\right)}\\ &=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}{\left(\operatorname{e}^{-\beta\left(t_{k}-t_{j}\right)}-1\right)}\\ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}{\sum_{j=1}^{i}{\left(\operatorname{e}^{-\beta\left(t_{i+1}-t_{j}\right)}-\operatorname{e}^{-\beta\left(t_{i}-t_{j}\right)}\right)}} &=\operatorname{e}^{-\beta t_{k}}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}{\operatorname{e}^{\beta t_{j}}}-k+1\end{aligned}